# Is there a way to call an API once instead of twice per output generated?

Tags: python, pandas, geocoding

Im trying to write code more efficiently in Python. Currently the app below fetches my desired output.However, it makes 2 calls per address

Reprex:

```
import pandas as pd
from geocodio import GeocodioClient

API_KEY = 'insert_your_key_here'

client = GeocodioClient(API_KEY)

customers = pd.read_csv("example.csv", header=None)
customers['address_string'] = customers[0].map(str) + ' ' + customers[1].map(str) + customers[2].map(str)

geocoded_acuracy = []
geocoded_acuracy_type = []

for address in customers['address_string'].values:
    geocoded_address = client.geocode(address)
    accuracy = geocoded_address.best_match.get("accuracy")
    accuracy_type = geocoded_address.best_match.get("accuracy_type")

    geocoded_acuracy.append(accuracy)
    geocoded_acuracy_type.append(accuracy_type)

customers['accuracy'] = geocoded_acuracy
customers['accuracy_type'] = geocoded_acuracy_type

results = customers[['address_string', 'accuracy', 'accuracy_type']]

results.to_csv('results.csv')
```

Although the code ran and I received my desired output. The code makes 2 calls to the api per address. Since there is a 2500/day limit it gets consumed fast. Is there a way to make the call for accuracy and accuracy type within a single call because acc to the documentation these just show up within the output dictionary of the original forward geocoding function itself. My objective is to make only 1 call per address.

Reprex of dataset(where address string is my only input in the above code):

```
    customers['address_string']
Out[5]: 
0         21236 Birchwood Loop, 99567, AK
1               1731 Bragaw St, 99508, AK
2            300 E Fireweed Ln, 99503, AK
3               4360 Snider Dr, 99654, AK
4     1921 W Dimond Blvd # 108, 99515, AK
5                2702 Peger Rd, 99709, AK
6              1651 College Rd, 99709, AK
7              898 Ballaine Rd, 99709, AK
8        23819 Immelman Circle, 99567, AK
9             9750 W Parks Hwy, 99652, AK
10           7205 Shorewood Dr, 99645, AK
Name: address_string, dtype: object
```

Comment: i am still confused, where it makes the two calls, when you have only one geocode function call. what is the exact value in customer['address_string'] ?

Comment: @venkatakrishnan it makes 2 calls per address because im calling accuracy and accuracy type. Each time I call it I consume 2 calls per address. I have edited my answer above with the output of customer['address_string']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API returns a JSON in the following format:

```py
from geocodio import GeocodioClient

client = GeocodioClient(YOUR_API_KEY)

location = client.geocode("1109 N Highland St, Arlington VA")
```

Returns:

```
{
  "input": {
    "address_components": {
      "number": "1109",
      "predirectional": "N",
      "street": "Highland",
      "suffix": "St",
      "formatted_street": "N Highland St",
      "city": "Arlington",
      "state": "VA",
      "zip": "22201",
      "country": "US"
    },
    "formatted_address": "1109 N Highland St, Arlington, VA 22201"
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "address_components": {
        "number": "1109",
        "predirectional": "N",
        "street": "Highland",
        "suffix": "St",
        "formatted_street": "N Highland St",
        "city": "Arlington",
        "county": "Arlington County",
        "state": "VA",
        "zip": "22201",
        "country": "US"
      },
      "formatted_address": "1109 N Highland St, Arlington, VA 22201",
      "location": {
        "lat": 38.886665,
        "lng": -77.094733
      },
      "accuracy": 1,
      "accuracy_type": "rooftop",
      "source": "Virginia GIS Clearinghouse"
    }
  ]
}
```

You should only need to make the query once and then retrieve all information from the JSON.

- [Batch geocoding](https://www.geocod.io/docs/?python#batch-geocoding)
- [Single geocoding](https://www.geocod.io/docs/?python#single-address)

### To get your information

```py
location['results'][0]['accuracy']
location['results'][0]['accuracy_type']
```

- Here's a great resource [Dictionaries in Python](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/)

### With your code:

- probably something like the following should work
- I've only updated the `for-loop`

```py
for address in customers['address_string'].values:
    geocoded_address = client.geocode(address)
    accuracy = geocoded_address['results'][0]['accuracy']
    accuracy_type = geocoded_address['results'][0]['accuracy_type']

    geocoded_acuracy.append(accuracy)
    geocoded_acuracy_type.append(accuracy_type)

customers['accuracy'] = geocoded_acuracy
customers['accuracy_type'] = geocoded_acuracy_type
```

### New code for batch processing:

- Given your addresses in a list:
- Using pandas

```py
from geocodio import GeocodioClient
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

addresses = ['21236 Birchwood Loop, 99567, AK',
             '1731 Bragaw St, 99508, AK',
             '300 E Fireweed Ln, 99503, AK',
             '4360 Snider Dr, 99654, AK',
             '1921 W Dimond Blvd # 108, 99515, AK',
             '2702 Peger Rd, 99709, AK',
             '1651 College Rd, 99709, AK',
             '898 Ballaine Rd, 99709, AK',
             '23819 Immelman Circle, 99567, AK',
             '9750 W Parks Hwy, 99652, AK',
             '7205 Shorewood Dr, 99645, AK']

client = GeocodioClient('api key')
locations = client.geocode(addresses)
df = json_normalize(locations, 'results')

                          formatted_address  accuracy        accuracy_type                                         source address_components.number address_components.street address_components.suffix address_components.formatted_street address_components.city     address_components.county address_components.state address_components.zip address_components.country  location.lat  location.lng address_components.predirectional
 21236 Birchwood Loop Rd, Chugiak, AK 99567      1.00              rooftop                      Municipality of Anchorage                     21236            Birchwood Loop                        Rd                   Birchwood Loop Rd                 Chugiak        Anchorage Municipality                       AK                  99567                         US     61.408788   -149.486656                               NaN
        1731 Bragaw St, Anchorage, AK 99508      1.00              rooftop                      Municipality of Anchorage                      1731                    Bragaw                        St                           Bragaw St               Anchorage        Anchorage Municipality                       AK                  99508                         US     61.204899   -149.808038                               NaN
     300 E Fireweed Ln, Anchorage, AK 99503      1.00              rooftop                      Municipality of Anchorage                       300                  Fireweed                        Ln                       E Fireweed Ln               Anchorage        Anchorage Municipality                       AK                  99503                         US     61.197860   -149.878311                                 E
     300 W Fireweed Ln, Anchorage, AK 99503      0.80              rooftop                      Municipality of Anchorage                       300                  Fireweed                        Ln                       W Fireweed Ln               Anchorage        Anchorage Municipality                       AK                  99503                         US     61.198304   -149.887737                                 W
          4360 Snider Dr, Wasilla, AK 99654      1.00  range_interpolation  TIGER/Line® dataset from the US Census Bureau                      4360                    Snider                        Dr                           Snider Dr                 Wasilla     Matanuska-Susitna Borough                       AK                  99654                         US     61.584604   -149.339148                               NaN
        4360 E Snider Dr, Wasilla, AK 99654      0.90              rooftop                      Matanuska-Susitna Borough                      4360                    Snider                        Dr                         E Snider Dr                 Wasilla     Matanuska-Susitna Borough                       AK                  99654                         US     61.584226   -149.340742                                 E
          4360 Snider Dr, Wasilla, AK 99654      0.90  range_interpolation  TIGER/Line® dataset from the US Census Bureau                      4360                    Snider                        Dr                           Snider Dr                 Wasilla     Matanuska-Susitna Borough                       AK                  99654                         US     61.584903   -149.338583                               NaN
    1921 W Dimond Blvd, Anchorage, AK 99515      1.00              rooftop                      Municipality of Anchorage                      1921                    Dimond                      Blvd                       W Dimond Blvd               Anchorage        Anchorage Municipality                       AK                  99515                         US     61.139078   -149.915706                                 W
         2702 Peger Rd, Fairbanks, AK 99709      1.00              rooftop                   Fairbanks North Star Borough                      2702                     Peger                        Rd                            Peger Rd               Fairbanks  Fairbanks North Star Borough                       AK                  99709                         US     64.822680   -147.779801                               NaN
       1651 College Rd, Fairbanks, AK 99709      1.00              rooftop                   Fairbanks North Star Borough                      1651                   College                        Rd                          College Rd               Fairbanks  Fairbanks North Star Borough                       AK                  99709                         US     64.862441   -147.754823                               NaN
       898 Ballaine Rd, Fairbanks, AK 99709      1.00              rooftop                   Fairbanks North Star Borough                       898                  Ballaine                        Rd                         Ballaine Rd               Fairbanks  Fairbanks North Star Borough                       AK                  99709                         US     64.899323   -147.828632                               NaN
      23819 Immelman Cir, Chugiak, AK 99567      1.00              rooftop                      Municipality of Anchorage                     23819                  Immelman                       Cir                        Immelman Cir                 Chugiak        Anchorage Municipality                       AK                  99567                         US     61.417786   -149.438269                               NaN
                         Big Lake, AK 99652      0.33                place  TIGER/Line® dataset from the US Census Bureau                       NaN                       NaN                       NaN                                 NaN                Big Lake     Matanuska-Susitna Borough                       AK                  99652                         US     61.517340   -149.953740                               NaN
        7205 Shorewood Dr, Palmer, AK 99645      1.00  range_interpolation  TIGER/Line® dataset from the US Census Bureau                      7205                 Shorewood                        Dr                        Shorewood Dr                  Palmer     Matanuska-Susitna Borough                       AK                  99645                         US     61.625942   -149.266667                               NaN
      7205 E Shorewood Dr, Palmer, AK 99645      0.90              rooftop                      Matanuska-Susitna Borough                      7205                 Shorewood                        Dr                      E Shorewood Dr                  Palmer     Matanuska-Susitna Borough                       AK                  99645                         US     61.626537   -149.268727                                 E
        7205 Shorewood Dr, Palmer, AK 99645      0.90  range_interpolation  TIGER/Line® dataset from the US Census Bureau                      7205                 Shorewood                        Dr                        Shorewood Dr                  Palmer     Matanuska-Susitna Borough                       AK                  99645                         US     61.625909   -149.266960                               NaN
```

Comment: I am aware of this @trenton. But I only want accuracy and accuracy_type from this entire JSON output.Also, im new to python. Its not rocket science but initially everyone has struggles

Comment: @JoelTharian Then the real question is, how do I access information in a JSON object.  The answer has been updated.

Comment: Rookie question -How do I implement the(to get your information) in my code to write to my csv output file?

Comment: @JoelTharian I've added a section updating the `for-loop`, but you should really use `Batch geocoding` for multiple addresses.  That will require updates to parse the JSON for all the returned values.

Comment: @JoelTharian See update at the bottom, implementing batch processing

Comment: Say I dont have to manually enter the addresses for the batch geocode and all my addresses are in a csv DF called customers. How would I run the same code on it to give me only formatted address,accuracy and accuracy type in my final output csv file

Comment: `addresses = customers['address_string'].tolist()` and `df[['formatted_address', 'accuracy', 'accuracy_type']].to_csv('my.csv', index=False)` or `df.iloc[:, 0:3].to_csv('my.csv', index=False)`

Comment: I receive KeyError: 'address_string'

Comment: `address_string` is the name you show in your dataframe at the top.  It just needs to be whatever the column name is.